# Where do I see the output of the printf statement, if the project is run for an STM32F407 board in the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, stm32, stm32f4discovery

In the **Eclipse IDE**, a project is ran using the GCC ARM cross compiler for an STM32F407 board. Now I want to view the output using **printf statements**.

However, the code is getting dumped in the board and the external peripherals are working fine. In the in-built console of Eclipse, there is no output.

**CubeMX** is the source code generator, the OS is **Linux (Ubuntu)** and the board is [Discovery STM32F407VGTX](http://st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html).

I want to print the "speed" variable, an uint32_t variable. A sensor reads the pulses using a 20-slot encoder and using the `systick` timer (which get called every one millisecond), and the counter is counted in encoder mode.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which board are you using?  You have to use "semihosting" to be able to print out to console, and one of your UART ports will be taken up, but it depends on which board you have. I use a Nucleo board and it works fine for me. I did have to use a special print library to be able to print out to the console in Eclipse with semihosting.

Comment: Goodmorning @DavidCAdams, It's a Discovery board, here it is http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f4discovery.html . Basically, I wanted to print the "speed" variable, an uint32_t variable. A sensor reads the pulses using a 20-slot encoder and using systick timer(which get called every one millisecond), the counter is counted in encoder-mode.